# Can I Scale my dependent variable by one of the independent ones and still use the independent one as a feature?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, endogeneity

I would like to predict $y_i$ (my variable at time step $i$) but find some merit in instead taking $y_i$ as percentage difference of a feature at that same step e.g $b_i$. So that I instead use $(y_i-b_i)/b_i$ as my prediction variable. I have been told that if I do so I can not then use $\frac{b_i-b_{i-1}}{b_{i-1}}$ as a one of the feature variables (someone quoted endogenous variables as the reason why I can't do this and saying that I cant predict $a-b$ as a function of $b$.)

TLDR:

Is there any reason why I can not use e.g linear regression to predict $\frac{y_i-b_i}{b_i}$ as a function of $\frac{b_i-b_{i-1}}{b_{i-1}}$?

Comment: let's say you are putting complete noise into your analysis, would you get significant results or somewhat biased results after your transformation?

Comment: Ah, you mean because I'm doing $\frac{y_i-b_i}{b_i}=f(X_i)+\epsilon_i$ I'm going to get $y_i-b_i=b_if(X_i)+b_i\epsilon_i$? and am therefore weighting my error by $b_i$ for each $y_i$?

Comment: Actually I would have just thought the above meant that my error with my new model is $1/b_i$ less than what it would be with the $y_i=g(X_i)+\epsilon_i$ (until i multiple it by $b_i$). So I'm not sure I see why my results would be biased

Comment: you will make your transformed variable dependent and highly correlated to your b

Comment: Is that a problem? $y_i$ is already extremely linear with $b_i$ anyway, which is why I wanted to make this transformation to pick out what features lead to y_i differing from it

Comment: yes, you are making it even more linear. Are you trying to find features that predict some proportion of variance in y that is not already predicted by b? in that case you do this simply just by including b in your model as covariate